# Pegar valor em Moeda e retirar "." e "," de um campo input?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input

Quando a pessoa digitar o valor no campo input com "." e ",", pego esse valor e deixo apenas número, estou fazendo isso utilizando o metodo "focusout". Pois desta forma quando a pessoa digitar o valor a muda de forma automárica para apenas número. Conseguir fazer sem problema. Mas se a pessoa coloca um valor R$ 1.500,00 ao inves de ficar apenas 1500 esta ficando 150000.

Abaixo segue código

```
<div style="max-width: 50%; margin: 50px auto;">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="valor-minimo" value="" />
</div>

<div style="max-width: 50%; margin: 50px auto;">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="valor-maximo" value="" />
</div>


<script>

    // Pega o valor em Moenda e retira o "." e "." do input valor-minimo
    const $campoValorMin = document.querySelector('#valor-minimo')

    $campoValorMin.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {

        $valorMin = event.target.value;
        $campoValorMin.value = $valorMin.replace(/[.,]/g, "")
        

    })

    // Pega o valor em Moenda e retira o "." e "." do input valor-maximo
    const $campoValorMax = document.querySelector('#valor-maximo')

    $campoValorMax.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {

        $valorMax = event.target.value;
        $campoValorMax.value = $valorMax.replace(/[.,]/g, "")

    })
</script>
```

Comment: E se a pessoa quiser colocar menos decimais como funciona ? por exemplo R$ 1500,5 ? Qual o valor que você espera interpretar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa dividir por 100, pois ao tirar a vírgula, você está acrescentando zeros a direita:

```js
    $campoValorMax.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {

        $valorMax = event.target.value;
        $campoValorMax.value = parseFloat($valorMax.replace(/[.,]/g, "")) / 100
    })
```

Agora, se precisar que continue sendo string, você precisa remover não apenas a virgula, mas o que vem depois dela também.

```js
   //retira o '.' e depois a ',' juntamente com os dois números depois desta
   $campoValorMax.value = $valorMax.replace(/([.])/g, "").replace(/[,]\d{2}/g,'')
```

Comment: Obrigado, Marcos Alexandre, era exatamente isso que eu precisava...

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar.